# jQuery: scroll to the next visible walkthrough tooltip

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've implemented some functions to display a walkthrough tooltips, but I can't find a way to make the screen scroll to the next visible tooltip when the `info-next` and `show-info` buttons are pressed.

There already are some answers to this kind of question, but they don't help me or I can't find the best way to implement them.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ucmvvqzh/4/

Here's my code:
HTML

```
<button class="show-info">display content</button>
<div class="info first_info current" data-index="0">
  <span>This is first</span>
    <button class="info-next">
    Next
  </button>
</div>
<div class="info second_info" data-index="1">
  <span>This is second</span>
    <button class="info-next">
    Next
  </button>
</div>
<div class="info third_info" data-index="2">
  <span>This is third</span>
  <button class="info-next">
    Next
  </button>
</div>
<div class="info fourth_info last" data-index="3">
  <span>Last</span>
    <button class="info-last">
    Close
    </button>
</div>
<div class="first">add here the first tooltip</div>
<div class="second">add here the second tooltip</div>
<div class="third">add here the third tooltip</div>
<div class="fourth">add here the fourth tooltip</div>
```

CSS

```
.first_info,
.second_info,
.third_info,
.fourth_info {
  display:none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}
.first, .second, .third, .fourth {position:relative;}
.first {top: 100px;}
.second {top: 300px;left: 50px;}
.third {top: 500px;left: 100px;}
.fourth {top: 750px;left: 150px;}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.show-info').click(function(){
    firstPos = $(".first").offset();
    secondPos = $(".second").offset();
    thirdPos = $(".third").offset();
    fourthPos = $(".fourth").offset();

    $('.first_info').css({
        left: firstPos.left + "px",
      top: firstPos.top + 30 + "px"
    })
    $('.second_info').css({
        left: secondPos.left + "px",
      top: secondPos.top + 30 + "px"
    })
    $('.third_info').css({
        left: thirdPos.left + "px",
      top: thirdPos.top + 30 + "px"
    })
    $('.fourth_info').css({
        left: fourthPos.left + "px",
      top: fourthPos.top + 30 + "px"
    })    

    $('.info.first_info').show();
  });
  $('.info-last').click(function(){
    $('.info').hide();
  });
  $('.info-next').click(function() {
      $('.current')
        .removeClass('current')
        .hide()
        .next(".info")
        .show()
        .addClass('current');
  });
});
```

I already tried to add the following code to `$('.info-next').click(function()` but with no result...

```
$('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: $('.info').offsetTop
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Do you want to create some kind of wizard? If so, try this http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples

Comment: Yes, it's already implemented, the jsfiddle contains only the functionality. These examples are not helping me...

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your click handlers:

```
$('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: $('.current').offset().top
}, 2000);
```

and correct setting the **current** class